# PowerApps combobox filter from another combobox

Tags: filter, combobox, powerapps

I have a number of combo boxes on a screen and they all use the same source "Table1" from an external excel sheet).

When I have selected a value from "Combobox 1" I would like it not to be available for selection in the other combo boxes... following on and on as items are selected.

I am very new to PowerApps and this is my first app. I have tried to filter...

filter(Table1 <> ComboBox2.Value) but receive the red cross.

If you could help me with the syntax for this that would be great.

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I had to build a collection which is added to by all the combo boxes with a remove when unselected also with the below syntax...

RemoveIf(COLLECTIONNAME,Dropdown = 1);
Collect(COLLECTIONNAME,{COLUMNNAME FROM COLLECTION:Self.Selected.Team,Dropdown:1});

Then the items had to be where not in the collection with the following syntax...

Filter(Table1, !(COLUMNNAME FROM TABLE 1 in COLLECTIONNAME.COLUMNNAME FROM COLLECTION))

Thanks for all the suggestions, hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

**Filter(Table1, ThisRecord.Value<> ComboBox1.Selected.Value )**

You can use the above function.

Here **ComboBox1** is the control name of the First combo box.
On the second Combo Box, on the **Items** property you can write the above formula. The formula filters the selected value in the combo box and that value is not shown in the second combo box, all other values are visible.

For more info on the use of filter function, visit the following link:

http://ashishcoder.com/courses/power-apps/topic-12/filter-function-in-power-apps.html

Thank you

Comment: ThisRecord is not necessary, but the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Filter() is the right choice here, but the syntax is important. Functions are case-sensitive. Filter with capital F would have displayed to you hints about what arguments it expects. Building on your formula, here's a corrected version:

```
Filter(Table1,FieldName <> ComboBox1.Value)
```

where FieldName is the name of the column bound in ComboBox1.